# Rails not loading CSS/javascript/images on ISP server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I have a Rails app that works fine on my local environment. But when I upload it to my ISP the app is not loading any of the assets in the public directory. Because the ISP uses .htaccess rewrites for Rails apps, I suspect this is the problem, but I'm pretty green on that sort of thing.

On the server, my rails app is deployed at `~/etc/rails_apps/myapp`

In my home dir there's a symlink `www -> etc/rails_apps/myapp/public`

Isn't the idea that the symlink loads the assets from `etc/rails_apps/myapp/public`? Am I missing something else?

The server is Mongrel, if that matters.
The `public/stylesheets` and `public/javascripts` dirs both have 755 permissions, if that matters.

Comment: What permissions does /etc/rails_apps/myapp/public have? Do you have any control over the .htaccess rewrite rules? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the Hosting environment that you are using whether its  shared host like Bluehost or Hosmonster or Dedicated Hosting Service .

If you are hosting in a Shared hosting environment , Then your rails root directory should be in /home/user-name/rails_apps. Since the shared host provider doesn't allow you to change the  permission of the /etc folder .

if your railsapps is in /home/user-name/rails_apps/yourapp  then  in the created symbolic link chmod 777  permission to the  created symobilic folder which will be your domain name inside the public_html folder .

ln -s ~/rails/your-rails-app-name/public your-domain-name-without-extension

example : ln -s ~/rails/your-rails-app-name/public stackoverflow

$ chmod 777  /public_html/stackoverflow

Hope this helps !